# Cast T to generic superclass with unknown type

Tags: swift

Let's say I have an array of type Foo with FooBar objects in it.

Bar <T> class is a generic class that inherits from Foo.

Then I have multiple FooBar classes, that inherits from Bar<T>, each with different generic type. (Bar<Int>, Bar<String>).

The problem is that I need to walk through the array of type Foo, check if na object is of type Bar<T>, cast it to Bar and set it's property.

Buty Swift won't allow me to cast to unknown type <T> and Bar<Any> doesn't match Bar<Int> or another...

I came up with two possible solutions - add new class to the hierarchy that inherits from Foo and is parent of Bar, but is not generic, and cast to this one or implement a protocol (which seems as much better solution).

What I'm really not sure about is if protocols are meant for this kind of stuff. In C-like lang, I would use an interface probably.

//Edit: Sample code

```
class Foo {

}

class Bar<T> : Foo {

    var delegate : SomeDelegate

}

class FooBar: Bar<Int> {

}

class FooBar2: Bar<String> {

}

let arr : [Foo] = [ FooBar(), FooBar2(), Foo() ]


for item in arr {

    // this is the problem - I need to match both String,Int or whathever the type is
    if let b = item as? Bar<Any> {
        b.delegate = self
    }
}
```

Comment: it would be much easier to follow your need by putting some sample code, and some "pseudo code" of what you would like to do.

Comment: @GiuseppeLanza Excuse me for not including the code. I've changed my question so now you can see what I was trying to achieve.